# Headless continuous integration with Jenkins

Tags: continuous-integration, jenkins

I’m trying to set up Jenkins on a RackSpace ArchLinux Cloud Server, but I’ve been unable to.

Whenever I try to access Jenkins site, I get this error:

```
AWT is not properly configured on this server. Perhaps you need to run your container with "-Djava.awt.headless=true"?

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.awt.X11FontManager.getDefaultPlatformFont(X11FontManager.java:779)
    at sun.font.SunFontManager$2.run(SunFontManager.java:428)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.font.SunFontManager.<init>(SunFontManager.java:371)
    at sun.awt.X11FontManager.<init>(X11FontManager.java:32)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:372)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:325)
    at sun.font.FontManagerFactory$1.run(FontManagerFactory.java:80)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.font.FontManagerFactory.getInstance(FontManagerFactory.java:71)
    at java.awt.Font.getFont2D(Font.java:489)
    at java.awt.Font.getFamily(Font.java:1186)
    at java.awt.Font.getFamily_NoClientCode(Font.java:1160)
    at java.awt.Font.getFamily(Font.java:1152)
    at java.awt.Font.toString(Font.java:1649)
    at hudson.util.ChartUtil.<clinit>(ChartUtil.java:229)
    at hudson.WebAppMain.contextInitialized(WebAppMain.java:175)
    at winstone.WebAppConfiguration.<init>(WebAppConfiguration.java:897)
    at winstone.HostConfiguration.initWebApp(HostConfiguration.java:131)
    at winstone.HostConfiguration.<init>(HostConfiguration.java:73)
    at winstone.HostGroup.initHost(HostGroup.java:85)
    at winstone.HostGroup.<init>(HostGroup.java:45)
    at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:197)
    at winstone.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:398)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at Main._main(Main.java:268)
    at Main.main(Main.java:96)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperJarApp.run(WrapperJarApp.java:394)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

So, what do you think it might be?

I’ve already tried setting JAVA_OPTS environmental variable, to no avail. I also tried executing Java with `-Djava.awt.headless=true`, or even setting it in conf/wrapper.conf as wrapper.app.parameter.3=-headless.

Any idea how may I tackle this problem? I’m so new at this...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you running Sun's Java or OpenJDK?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[Finally found a solution](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+got+java.awt.headless+problem).

Believe it or not, it was actually just a matter of installing ttf-dejavu font!

I’m ashamed...

Comment: Don't be!! It can happen to anyone! The Headless error can be very tricky to understand the route cause!

Comment: In my case (also Arch Linux here) having ttf-dejavu did not help when tried to run Jenkins with OpenJDK. Only after installing Oracle JDK Jenkins started without the specified error.

Answer (score 31):

On my fedora 17 64Bit machine, I had OpenJDK 1.7 installed and I yum installed Jenkins which was having the same issue. Setting up -Djava.awt.headless=true did not help.

Finally solved the issue by installing dejavu-sans-fonts:

```
yum install dejavu-sans-fonts
```

Comment: This worked for me on CentOS with OpenJDK 1.7 but only after I also installed fontconfig.

Comment: OpenSUSE: `zypper install dejavu-fonts`

Comment: Seconding that a clean CentOS 7 with Adopt OpenJDK 11 needed fontconfig installed, which has dejavu-sans-fonts as a dependency. Just dejavu-sans-fonts by themselves didn't do it.

Answer (score 9):

Installation of **java-1.6.0-openjdk** resulted in the following dependency's:

- fontconfig
- libXfont
- libfontenc
- ttmkfdir
- xorg-x11-font-utils
- xorg-x11-fonts-Type1

After the installation of those packages and a restart of **jenkis**, everything worked as designed.

Comment: Oracle java7 also need this dependencies, its not just openjdk

Comment: @Zab0815, just curious, what distro that you tried on and how did you get such a list of dependency?  I just tried on both CentOS 6.3 and Fedora 17, with both java-1.6.0-openjdk and java-1.7.0-openjdk.  I used yum deplist together with some shell filters. I got quite different output, but yours works! Thanks!

Comment: This actually worked. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6):

Having an ArchLinux 64 bit headless server, I have successfully configured jenkins to work by following steps:

1. Installed ttf-dejavu package
2. Installed fontconfig packages
3. added to /etc/conf.d/tomcat7:

   CATALINA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true"

Comment: Installing `ttf-dejavu` and `fontconfig` worked for fixing it on WSL

Answer (score 2):

For me installing the fonts didn't help at all. For me it actually missed the `fontconfig` package.

Details: https://noobient.com/2014/10/01/jenkins-service-unavailable/

Answer (score 1):

```
pacman -S ttf-dejavu
```

fixed it for my Archlinux box

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
 
I'm using MobaXterm as a terminal for my linux account, and for me the solution was in MobaXterm. I had to enable X11 under Settings --> Configurations.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux Server release 6.2 (Santiago) , you just need to specify below command.

```
export CATALINA_OPTS="-DJENKINS_HOME=/opt/itmsetup/apache-tomcat-6.0.37/jenkins -Xmx750m -Djava.awt.headless=true"
```

this has solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Installing `openjdk-7-jre-headless` and `ttf-dejavu` made the difference for me on Ubuntu 12.04 LTC (Precise). The fonts are referenced by the font setup of the Java installation and the OpenJDK 7 package depends on `libfontconfig1` and will thus actually use the fonts.

I'm using Jenkins from http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/debian/ and by default you will get `openjdk-6-jre-headless` since the `jenkins` package depends on `default-jre-headless`, which in turn pulls in `openjdk-6-jre-headless`.

You can swap the packages using

```
$ aptitude install openjdk-7-jre-headless
$ aptitude remove default-jre-headless openjdk-6-jre-headless
```

Answer (score 0):

See the [wiki page](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+got+java.awt.headless+problem) on this topic. Also cf. [PR 538](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/pull/538).

Comment: I linked to the wiki page in my response, but I had not seen that Pull Request. Thanks for the contribution!

Answer (score -1):

By adding `CATALINA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true"` in `setclasspath.sh` file of `tomcat/bin` directory solved the problem.