# Jenkins Deployment: AWT is not properly configured on this server. -Djava.awt.headless=true"?

Tags: java, tomcat, jenkins

Hi Stackoverflow friends

I've recently configured Jenkins Server into Apache Tomcat 7.0.42
The procedure that I make was deploy the jenkins.war file into tomcat servlet container.

Here I make reference some important considerations:

- My machine is a CentOS 6.4 Server:

  [root@safe2school srv]# cat /etc/redhat-release
  CentOS release 6.4 (Final)
  [root@safe2school srv]#
- My JDK version is JDK 1.7 UPDATE 45, this is the official Oracle JDK

  [root@safe2school srv]# java -version
  java version "1.7.0_45"
  Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
  Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)
  [root@safe2school srv]#

I've tried with the installation of dejavu-sans-fonts (yum install dejavu-sans-fonts
) and set the envoronment variable export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djava.awt.headless=true"
in the file /etc/bashrc but all these options doesn't work.

The output for this error is in the following image (https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNM8m.png):

There is some alternative that you can support me in these task?

I appreciate your help. Thanks :)

Comment: I see that there is different alternatives for solve this problem. I install  xorg-x11-xinit-session.x86_64 xorg-x11-server-Xdmx.x86_64 packages with the command yum install xorg-x11-xinit-session.x86_64 xorg-x11-server-Xdmx.x86_64
 and the problem is solved. I don't

Comment: The best solution is definitely to use the headless property. Apparently it's not taking it for you, i.e. jenkins is starting without that options being passed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Headless continuous integration with Jenkins](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8109607/headless-continuous-integration-with-jenkins)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try locating the file:

```
 /etc/sysconfig/jenkins
```

and inside it, the line: JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS=...

Make sure it has the headless option, e.g. :

```
JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Djava.awt.headless=true"
```

Otherwise, please indicate more specifically how you start your Jenkins instance.

Comment: Patrice, I deploy jenkins on apache tomcat (using the file jenkins.war). According to previous comment, I start my jenkins instance with a initialization script /etc/init.d/jenkins. This script start the apache tomcat application container that host the jenkins server.

Comment: Can you edit the JAVA_OPTS (or rather CATALINA_OPTS) in the /etc/init.d/jenkins ? to include the java.awt.headless property. It will then be available to the deployed Jenkins app.

Comment: For Ubuntu edit /etc/default/jenkins adding: `JAVA_ARGS="-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Djava.awt.headless=true"`

Answer (score 5):

I just ran into these messages switching from OpenJDK 8 to OpenJDK 11. None of these steps helped. But make sure "fontconfig" is installed, which solved my issue!

Comment: This also worked for me. Jenkins with OpenJDK on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: This also did the trick for me. Jenkins with Oracle Java SE 11.0.18 on Ubuntu 22.04. Thanks!