# Exception in GroovyHookScript while starting the Jenkins server

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-scriptler

Facing issue with starting the Jenkins instance.. here is the log,
I am using 1.542 (also tried with previous releases but no success)

Anybody is facing this kind of issue?

It looked very similar to https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-20609 but not sure if thats the case

```
Running from: /home/jenkins/jenkins-latest.war
webroot: $user.home/.jenkins
Dec 04, 2013 11:11:38 PM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog info
INFO: jetty-8.y.z-SNAPSHOT
Dec 04, 2013 11:11:38 PM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog info
INFO: Extract jar:file:/home/jenkins/jenkins-latest.war!/ to /tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-jenkins-latest.war--any-/webapp
Dec 04, 2013 11:11:41 PM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog info
INFO: NO JSP Support for , did not find org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet
Jenkins home directory: /root/.jenkins found at: $user.home/.jenkins
Dec 04, 2013 11:11:41 PM hudson.util.BootFailure publish
SEVERE: Failed to initialize Jenkins
hudson.util.AWTProblem: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at hudson.WebAppMain.contextInitialized(WebAppMain.java:182)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:782)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:424)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:774)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:249)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1242)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:717)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:494)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:95)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:282)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
        at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:154)
        at winstone.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:354)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at Main._main(Main.java:293)
        at Main.main(Main.java:98)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at sun.awt.X11FontManager.getDefaultPlatformFont(X11FontManager.java:779)
        at sun.font.SunFontManager$2.run(SunFontManager.java:432)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.font.SunFontManager.<init>(SunFontManager.java:375)
        at sun.awt.X11FontManager.<init>(X11FontManager.java:32)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:374)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:327)
        at sun.font.FontManagerFactory$1.run(FontManagerFactory.java:83)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.font.FontManagerFactory.getInstance(FontManagerFactory.java:74)
        at java.awt.Font.getFont2D(Font.java:490)
        at java.awt.Font.getFamily(Font.java:1187)
        at java.awt.Font.getFamily_NoClientCode(Font.java:1161)
        at java.awt.Font.getFamily(Font.java:1153)
        at java.awt.Font.toString(Font.java:1650)
        at hudson.util.ChartUtil.<clinit>(ChartUtil.java:229)
        at hudson.WebAppMain.contextInitialized(WebAppMain.java:181)
        ... 19 more

Dec 04, 2013 11:11:42 PM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog warn
WARNING: Failed startup of context w.{,file:/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-jenkins-latest.war--any-/webapp/},/home/jenkins/jenkins-latest.war
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at jenkins.util.groovy.GroovyHookScript.run(GroovyHookScript.java:63)
        at hudson.util.BootFailure.publish(BootFailure.java:43)
        at hudson.WebAppMain.contextInitialized(WebAppMain.java:244)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:782)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:424)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:774)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:249)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1242)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:717)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:494)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:95)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:282)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
        at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:154)
        at winstone.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:354)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at Main._main(Main.java:293)
        at Main.main(Main.java:98)

Dec 04, 2013 11:11:42 PM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog info
INFO: Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8080
Dec 04, 2013 11:11:42 PM winstone.Logger logInternal
INFO: Winstone Servlet Engine v2.0 running: controlPort=disabled
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running on FreeBSD on OpenJDK7, I was missing package `x11-fonts/fontconfig`.
Installing it fixed the problem.

This other thread helped:

[Headless continuous integration with Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8109607/headless-continuous-integration-with-jenkins)

Answer (score 1):

You should try this java argument on your start:

```
-Djava.awt.headless=true
```

Seems similar to the font problem shown at: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+got+java.awt.headless+problem

Answer (score 1):

For me `-Djava.awt.headless=true` didn't help at all. In fact, it's already specified in the Fedora default config. For me it missed the fontconfig package.

```
yum install fontconfig
```

And voila, it worked.

Details: http://vault-tec.info/post/98877792626/jenkins-service-unavailable

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem on RedHat 6 after upgrading Open JDK. Running the following fixed the problem.

```
yum install dejavu-fonts dejavu-lgc-sans-mono-fonts dejavu-sans-fonts dejavu-sans-mono-fonts dejavu-serif-fonts
```