# Jenkins Deployment on linux

Tags: java, tomcat, jenkins

I have configured `Jenkins` server into `Apache tomcat 9.0.0M4` , I deployed the `jenkins.war` files into tomcat server.

The below error message appears when trying to navigate to `localhost:8080/jenkins`.

> (awt is not properly configured on this server. perhaps you need to
>   run the container with "-Djava.awt.headless=true")

HELP Please!!!

Comment: https://sippingcocoa.wordpress.com/2010/10/03/installing-hudson-to-run-as-a-java-web-application-using-tomcat-on-snow-leopard-server/   you can try this link

Comment: Thanks @RishiKeshPathak , Can i got a contact info for you on skype

Comment: And did you try to run the tomcat container with this option (-Djava.awt.headless=true)?

Comment: @Henry could you please give me the steps to do this??

Comment: It is an option to the `java` command that starts the tomcat container. Where exactly you have to specify this depends on the linux distribution. You need to do some research.

Comment: maybe duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8109607/headless-continuous-integration-with-jenkins